# Duplicated login.phtml in CE 1.9

Tags: template, login, ce-1.9.0.1

Does anyone know why the login template is duplicated in CE 1.9 ? (see image)

Thanks.

[image: Different login templates]

Comment: One is from Mage_Customer and one is from Mage_Persistant but to be honest, I have no idea, what Mage_Persistant does

Comment: I was looking forward editing translations, and I just had this quick insight that the CSV to be changed is Mage_[1stDirInUrlPath].csv, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not 100% sure, I pondered the same thing some month or so ago and decided that `template/persistent/customer` replaced `template/customer` at some point (even when persistent shopping cart have been turned off). The only reason why we still have `template/customer` is backward compatibility.

I guess same applied to other templates under `persistent` as well.